# How can I determine the RSSI value of a detected device on Wi-Fi Direct?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, rssi

How can we get the received signal strength from a device when connecting peer to peer? Is there a function available in service Wifi-Direct to get the RSSI from the available devices? I've been searching and I can't find a way. Can someone point me in the correct direction? Thanks for the time.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/check-rssi-by-monitoring-of.html

Comment: It isn't about my question. It returns the RSSI for connected wireless network not connected WiFi-direct!

Comment: http://iswwwup.com/t/d1505df3b66b/android-how-can-i-get-the-rssi-value-of-a-detected-device-on-wi-fi-direct.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention but it isn't an answer for my question. It is a way for returning RSSI value of Wireless device which RSSI's strength changes. It isn't about signal strength of P2P/WiFi-Direct connection.